# IPhone 5c volume problems

Tags: audio

Ringer and message alerts does not always working. Volume up in settings and silencer is off. Help. I have tried shutting it down.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known bug with the Facebook app which lowers the volume if you have it running in the background. Try double tapping the home button twice and remove Facebook from there and see if that fixes it the issue.